# Count average value of every 6th column in one row via VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

Right now I'm writing macro on VBA , I almost finished it, but right now i'm stuck on one issue. I can't understand how should I count average value of range that consists of every 6th column of my table.
In excel this formula looks like "=AVG(I3, O3, U3...HE3)"

I tried to use macro recorder but it was just hard-coding average value by repeating the whole formula and every cell address. But my table updates everyday and everyday I add 6 new columns at the end of the table, left from last column and last column is column that stores average value of every 6th column of a row.
I tried to do it through loop and I think that I'm pretty close to solving this issue, but I don't understand how to add looped values to a particular cell with formula.

Here is my code:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 8
For i = 8 To rng.Columns.Count Step 6
rng.Cells(3, rng.Columns.Count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng.Cells(3,i))
Next i
```

rng - is Range variable that stores my table.

With above code I managed to loop through all cells that I need to count avg value, but I don't understand how to get values of these cells to a particular cell that counts avg value.
Could you please help me?

Comment: Do you want it to be a formula or just the value?

Comment: Both options work for me. The main purpose is to get the value =)

Comment: Do you mean Range().Formula = "AVERAGE(...)" ?

Comment: since you are looping through the values one by one, you can't use Average (you would be calculating the average of a single cell). Instead, track the number of cells found and the sum, and divide at the end.

Comment: @andreas provided a good answer.

Comment: Good work on your first question. Far better than most first questions. Good, concise description and enough code for us to understand but not anything that is unrelated to the question. Top notch!

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for helping, appreciate that =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just sum the values then divide by the count of (columns-8)/6.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim sum as long
i = 8
sum = 0
For i = 8 To rng.Columns.Count Step 6
    sum = sum + rng.Cells(3,i).value
Next i

rng.Cells(3, rng.Columns.Count).offset(0,1).value = sum/((rng.columns.count-8)/6) ' I assumed you want the value in rng.columns.count +1, since but change it if you want.
```

EDIT, can't use rng.columns.count+1 I think since the range ends at the count. Changed it to offset.

Also note that we have no error checking in this code.
I would suggest something like `If Isnumber(rng.Cells(3,i).value) then` before adding to the sum since a string value will break the code

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that works almost perfectly, but for some reason, when I use this code, the number of iterated values is lower than it actually is by 1. For instance, if we looped through 36 cells -  the formula is gonna be sum/35.
I couldn't understand the reason for that, maybe it depends on data types of counting numbers, so I just added +1 to the formula. It looks like: 
sum / ((rng.columns.count-8)/6)+1). 
Tested it on different samples and the average value was correct.

Comment: I would probably also do the same. The only thing I can think of is that we start on 8, and we subtract 8. Perhaps it should subtract 7 then? If you could create a smaller version of your file with just say 12 columns then it's easier to debug a code. Use F8 to step in to the code and see what all the values are. You could also add `debug.print rng.columns.count` and `debug.print ((rng.columns.count-8)/6) ' or with the +1` just to make sure you get correct values.

Comment: @Denis I see your edit now. Didn't see that as I was typing the above. Just make sure you get an integer value out of `((rng.columns.count-8)/6)+1)` because it should be an integer.

Comment: For some reason my formula counts the number of iterated values incorrectly, one cell is missing. For instance instead of sum/36, my formula performs sum/35. Couldn't understand the issue, Feels like my loop doesn't take last value, but I checked it using debug and everything there was fine. Once again checked my +1 formula with different samples and different tables and everything was OK, so I'm just gonna leave it like that. Thanks for you help again!

Answer (score 0):

I also found out an alternative method to do this, it's similar to @Andreas, but I offer to use in-loop counter to get the number of iterated values that are not empty.
In my case I need to get average value of range of cells that are separated by 6 columns. I have a big table with a lot of columns and rows and I need that average value for each row, so here is @Andreas modified code:

```
Sub countAVG()
 
Dim i As Integer               ' row
Dim j As Integer               ' column
Dim sum As Long                ' sum variable that stores sum of all iterated values
Dim numberOfValues As Long     ' variable that stores the number of iterated values (that are not empty)
Dim rng As Range
 
Set rng = Range("B2").CurrentRegion
sum = 0
numberOfValues = 0
i = 3                          ' start from 3rd row
j = 8                          ' and 8th column
For i = 3 To rng.Rows.Count Step 1
    For j = 8 To rng.Columns.Count - 1 Step 6   ' skip 6 columns from every cell
        If IsEmpty(rng.Cells(i, j)) Then        ' if cell is empty then we skip it
        numberOfValues = numberOfValues         ' by leaving our number of cells as it is
        sum = sum                                                                            ‘ same with sum
        Else:
        numberOfValues = numberOfValues + 1     ' otherwise add 1 to a current number of cells values
        sum = sum + rng.Cells(i, j).Value       ' sum not empty cell value with our previous sum
        End If
    Next j
    On Error Resume Next    ' turning off error notifications in case all values are empty (better to use IsEmpty())
    rng.Cells(i, rng.Columns.Count).Offset(0, 1).Value = sum / numberOfValues
    On Error GoTo 0         ' turning back error notifications
    sum = 0
    numberOfValues = 0
Next i
 
End Sub
```